# How to resize the layout properly? - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, sony, sony-smartwatch

Im trying to make an app for the sony smart watch 2.

Im trying to make a basic converter app which consists of one text box, two radio buttons and one button. Yet when testing on the watch everything is massive. If I resize things in eclipse things disappear and other things what is happening? Picture of it on watch:http://content.screencast.com/users/jeremyc12/folders/Jing/media/050d6158-1daa-4ebe-8eb2-ed8a46e3d024/2014-04-23_1334.png

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/smart_watch_2_control_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/smart_watch_2_control_height"
android:background="@color/myColor"
android:onClick="calculate"
tools:ignore="PxUsage" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:width="5px" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/kmh" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="@string/miles" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="@string/calc" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I see here:

1. As Aritra pointed out, make sure in your XML layout that you aren't doing any scaling.  So don't use "dp" just "px".
2. There are only a few Views in Android supported on SW2.  See here for details:
   http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/aef/control/Control.Intents#EXTRA_DATA_XML_LAYOUT

   EditText, RadioButton and Button views are not included there so thats why you're seeing some strange issues even without scaling.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:onClick="calculate" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:width="5px" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="kmh"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="miles" 
        android:textSize="8sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="calculate" 
        android:textSize="8sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you designing your view only for that device??

Comment: as i dont have the device i cant be sure designing the layout... you could decrease the size of the views to accomodate it into the screen...also see my edited answer if that helps......

Comment: Size of the views? How do you do that?

Comment: I mean to say fix the height and width of the views in pixels to accomodate it in the screen